# Text is not line breaking, no matter what

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the jsfiddle
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckb2vvyz/1/)

code:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-5" style="padding-right:0px;">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjI4NzA5OTg1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzc0MjU5OTE@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,675,1000_AL_.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></div>
            <div class="col-xs-7" style="background-color:#CBD4C2; padding-left:0;">
          
                <p>asjkfnaskjdnkasdnkasnsdkjasndkjansdkjnasjdbaskjsdnbjhbdskajad</p>
                kjadsbnjkasndkjasndkjasndkjasndkjasndkjnaskdjnaskjdnsakjdnaskjdnkjasdn
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: add style for the div:     word-break: break-all;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some css to fix this:

```
.wrap-text {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

And then:

```
<p class="wrap-text">asjkfnaskjdnkasdnkasnsdkjasndkjansdkjnasjdbaskjsdnbjhbdskajad
            kjadsbnjkasndkjasndkjasndkjasndkjasndkjnaskdjnaskjdnsakjdnaskjdnkjasdn</p>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckb2vvyz/6/)

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy. It always did worked just by default, and now instaly it didn't. "_ "

Comment: Welcome to the life of developing ;) Glad it worked out!

Comment: damn you beat me to the answer by a few sec :)  GJ :)

Answer (score 1):

add `word-break:break-word` to its container 
see below snippet or fiddle > [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/ckb2vvyz/8/)

```css
.col-xs-7{
  word-break:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-5" style="padding-right:0px;">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjI4NzA5OTg1OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzc0MjU5OTE@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,675,1000_AL_.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></div>
            <div class="col-xs-7" style="background-color:#CBD4C2; padding-left:0;">
          
                <p>asjkfnaskjdnkasdnkasnsdkjasndkjansdkjnasjdbaskjsdnbjhbdskajad</p>
                kjadsbnjkasndkjasndkjasndkjasndkjasndkjnaskdjnaskjdnsakjdnaskjdnkjasdn
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but i suggest you don't use plain text. instead wrap all the text inside a tag, for example a `<p>` like so :

```
 <p>asjkfnaskjdnkasdnkasnsdkjasndkjansdkjnasjdbaskjsdnbjhbdskajad
               kjadsbnjkasndkjasndkjasndkjasndkjasndkjnaskdjnaskjdnsakjdnaskjdnkjasdn</p>
```

( also use `break-word` )